# Автоматический редирект с дублей страниц на основную страницу через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Сам вопрос: CMS генерирует дубли страниц новостей в большом количестве вида https://site.ru/id-slug/??? (в конце после слеша произвольные цифры и буквы или все вместе). В движке предусмотрен тег rel='canonical', но Яндекс их видет все и выдал в Вебмастере предупреждение о дублях страниц!
Как сделать автоматический 301 редирект таких страниц на основную страницу http://site.ru/id-slug/

Comment: mod_rewrite тебе поможет. Уточни, я правильно понял, что все что идет после последнего слеша должно игнорировать и пользователя должно перекидывать на uri без все лабуды... то есть /id-slug/abrakadabra => /id-slug/ или /id-top/abrakaabra на /id-top/ ?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/154643/ может тебе поможет эта статья?

Comment: Да, Уточни, я правильно понял, что все что идет после последнего слеша должно игнорировать и пользователя должно перекидывать на uri без все лабуды...